# HTML div tag inside a div tag,what's the purpose of it?

Tags: html, tags

i am new to HTML and i am struggling to understand when and specifically why we use a div inside a div.For example:

```
 <section id="home-bg-parallax" class="h-100 overflow-hidden p-0 w-100">
 <!-- BG Parallax -->
 <div class="bg-parallax bg-overlay-black-8"></div>

 <div class="h-100 left-0 position-absolute top-0 w-100">
 <div class="container h-100">
 <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
 <div class="col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
 <span class="font-alt font-w-600 opacity-9-5 letter-spacing-2 text-large 
 text-uppercase text-white">Welcome To Traversy Media</span>

 <h2 class="font-alt font-w-700 letter-spacing-2 m-0 mt-3 text-uppercase 
 text-white title-xs-extra-large title-sm-extra-large-3 title-extra-large- 
 4">
 Web Development Tutorials & Courses
 </h2>



<span class="bg-base-color d-block mt-4 sep-line-extra-thick-long"></span>
</div>
<!-- //.col-lg-9 -->
</div>
<!-- //.row -->
</div>
<!-- //.container -->
</div>
<!-- //.h-100 -->
</section>
```

This is code from TraversyMedia.com.Maybe this question is dumb but i cannot figure out why we do this.If somebody can help me,i would be grateful.

Comment: Div stands for division. You can use them to place your content how you like. It doesn’t matter how many you use or where you use them, but there are proper standards for how your code should be structured. A div within a div, as you mention, is perfectly acceptable and a common way of displaying our content.

Comment: So if it is the same,why do people write many divs inside divs?I mean,you can write less code,why not?

Comment: It's not really possible to tell why multiple div elements were used here, we can't see what CSS and JavaScript has been applied to them.

Comment: The number of divs in a typical page, the layout may require a number of different groupings to arrange the content (e.g. multiple columns). For interactive effects, you may also need divs to change (hide/show/animate) a group of elements, or to target sub-groups or individual elements. Good programmers use exactly the amount of divs which are needed and no more. Hope that helps a little

Answer (score 0):

The uses of the different div tags are to group elements together if they will all share a style or need to be positioned relative to the div they are in. For example, you may have a div for the header bar of your webpage but then have another div inside this so that you can just make adjustments to the navigation part of the header rather than the whole header.